# A simple Select taking too long

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as follows:

[image]

```
    SELECT DrugID,
            DrugName,
            Method
     FROM DrugMaster_Names WITH (NOLOCK);
```

A simple select query like above takes about 13 seconds for only 3585 records(rows) but if I remove DrugName from the query it takes just 1 sec. I'm trying to optimize this query and have tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work. 
I need help optimizing this query. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the data in that `DrugName` column is quite long - close to 2k per record - then it's a reasonable amount of data you're pulling with your query: ~6MB. Are you running this over the network or executing the query on the same machine as the DB? Are you running on a DB with very low throughput - e.g. on a Basic tier Azure DB?

If you truncate the `DrugName` does it make it much faster:

```
SELECT DrugID,
        left(DrugName, 20) as DrugName_Short,
        Method
 FROM DrugMaster_Names WITH (NOLOCK);
```

Comment: Truncating column does not improve the performance..I also tried adding an index, it didnt work either.

Comment: Do you have similar problems running queries against other tables? If you run with Show Query Plan on where does it say the work is done? How are you running it?